# Can problems happen when multiple Python processes create a .pyc file?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a large number of Python processes launching at the same time from a common directory.

If a Python source file has been recently modified the interpreter will compile a `.pyc` file.

If there are multiple processes simultaneously trying to build a `.pyc` for the same Python source file, can this create a race condition or other issues?

Will Python (or `cpython` specifically) guarantee concurrency protection when compiling?

I'm aware of methods that could be used to avoid this, I'm only interested in understanding if this use case can be problematic.

Comment: I believe its not a problem. pyc will update automatically when  there's a changes with your py.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally no, when CPython [write bytecode cache file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L873), it first write to a temporary file, then [move to the desired location with `os.replace`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L106). `os.replace` uses [`rename(2)` system call](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Modules/posixmodule.c#L3995) underlying, `rename()` is atomic if the OS/filesystem does not crash in the middle. As a result bytecode file write is atomic.

IMHO what you should worry about is bytecode cache file stale checking. Python check cache file freshness with source file `stat.mtime` (and file size). The caveat is, resolution of `mtime` being used by python is [one second](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L466), thus if one process modified source file while another process is writing cache file in the same second, left the bytecode cache file inconsistent with source and will not get refreshed later. Good news is [pep-0552](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0552/) get accepted, changed to hashed based cache file, which will take care of this case.